# allow git acess under chroot

Tags: ssh, git, chroot

The server has set up `chroot` environment.Users can access the server by `sftp`.
More than that,they need to use `git` aslo.I was following this link [creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access](http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access),copied `/bin/bash` `/usr/bin/git-shell` to the `/home/someuser/bin/bash`and `/home/someuser/usr/bin/git-shell` and also the `l2chroot` part.

```
/home/someuser/lib#ls -al -R
 total 12 drwxr-xr-x  3 git  git  4096 Jul 24 15:21 . drwxr-xr-x 25
 root root 4096 Jul 24 15:21 .. drwxr-xr-x  2 git  git  4096 Jul 24
 15:21 x86_64-linux-gnu
 
 ./x86_64-linux-gnu: total 2888 drwxr-xr-x 2 git git    4096 Jul 24
 15:21 . drwxr-xr-x 3 git git    4096 Jul 24 15:21 ..
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 git git 1868984 Jul 24 15:21 libc.so.6
 -rw-r--r-- 1 git git   14608 Jul 24 15:21 libdl.so.2
 -rw-r--r-- 1 git git  456632 Jul 24 15:21 libpcre.so.3
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 git git  138696 Jul 24 15:21 libpthread.so.0
 -rw-r--r-- 1 git git   31712 Jul 24 15:21 librt.so.1
 -rw-r--r-- 1 git git  130224 Jul 24 15:21 libselinux.so.1
 -rw-r--r-- 1 git git  167240 Jul 24 15:21 libtinfo.so.5
 -rw-r--r-- 1 git git  104864 Jul 24 15:21 libz.so.1
```

But I login with `someuser` it complains:

```
Last login: Mon Jul 24 16:59:19 2017 from 114.***.189
**/usr/bin/git-shell: Not a directory**
```

First I want git users be able to use git.Second don't want them be able to read every file on system.
How to make it work?

**UPDATE:**
`sshd_config` sftp part

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f AUTH -l INFO
Match group sftpusers
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp -l INFO -f AUTH
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no

Match group git
  ChrootDirectory /home/%u
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a git in chroot (there is no good reason to do that once you will not allow shell access), you need to include the executable in the chroot. Just copy the one from the system (including all the dynamically linked libraries).

Comment: so could forbid the sftp use for the git user? just don't want them have read ability everywhere.

Comment: You didnt write anything about your configuration, but if you use ForceCommnd in sshd_config, it will not allow sftp connections.

Comment: add my sshd_config.First I want git users be able to use git.Second don't want them be able to read every file on system.

Comment: That is exactly what `forcecommand /usr/bin/git-shell` does

Comment: I was using `chsh git` to `/usr/bin/git-shell`.And it complains `/usr/bin/git-shell: Not a directory`.After using `forcomand /usr/bin/git-shell` and restart sshd it complains same way.

Comment: What do you mean by "I was using chsh git to /usr/bin/git-shell."?

Comment: "used" `chsh git` which would change the default shell for user git to "/usr/bin/git-shell"

Comment: You should not change the users shell. Force command in sshd_config is enough.

Comment: `chsh git` back to `/bin/bash` and use `Forcecommand /usr/bin/git-shell`.After login it complains `/bin/bash is not a directory`

Answer (score 1):

@Shihe Zhang, since I can only reply to you if I have '50 reputation', I'm going to reply here...
I suspect the error you were getting, `/usr/bin/git-shell: Not a directory`, was due to required libraries not being available in the chroot.

For example, when I run `ldd /usr/bin/git-shell`, I get variables libraries in /lib and /lib64. If these are `mount --bind`ed into the chroot. I also then needed to mount '/dev' as well.

So doing the following fixed the issue (at least for me):

```
for i in lib lib64 dev; do mkdir /home/git/$i; mount --bind -o ro /$i /home/git/$i; done
```